# Xcode 12.4: Building for iOS Simulator, but the linked and embedded framework 'GoogleCast.framework' was built for iOS + iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, sdk, chromecast, xcode12, xcframework

I can't be the only one using Google Chromecast SDK for iOS on a Xcode 12.4 project. So, has anyone got a fix for this cause I can see google hasn't posted any sort of fix or workaround on the installation/setup page.

Answer (score 1):

Change `Validate Workspace` setting in Xcode Build Settings to `YES`.

Comment: This allows the project to build but when archiving it, it doesn't open, it crashes instantly.

Comment: @DavidVelarde the answer is correct (was struggling with that thing myself recently); could you provide the crash error message? mb I'll be able to help